# Javascript/jQuery remove all characters from string except occurrences between specific characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Using `efvss 3452 XT-123454 ghhs444d efvss XT-6336 ghhsd efq435vss XT-554 ghhsd efvss XT-23427 ghhs55d efvss XT-24` as an example string I want to remove all characters except for the the parts containing `XT-number` (eg. `XT-123454`).

I have this code(it doesn't return what I'm looking for):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    string = "efvss 3452 XT-123454 ghhs444d efvss XT-6336 ghhsd efq435vss XT-554 ghhsd efvss XT-23427 ghhs55d efvss XT-24";
    string = string.match(/(XT-)(.*)(\s)/g);
    document.write(string);
});
```

Desired output should be `XT-123454, XT-554, XT-23427, XT-24`

Comment: `/XT-\d+/g` should do (obviously, this stops at the first non-digit number - and space is non-digit.

Comment: Yes this did it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to match all the `XT-##` parts of the string.

```
var str = 'efvss XT-123454 ghhsd efvss XT-6336 ghhsd efvss XT-554 ghhsd efvss XT-23427 ghhsd efvss XT-24';
var regex = /\bXT-\d+\b/g;
var matches = str.match(regex);
< ["XT-123454", "XT-6336", "XT-554", "XT-23427", "XT-24"]
```

To recreate the string with only the parts you want use `.join()`:

```
var finalString = matches.join(' ');
< "XT-123454 XT-6336 XT-554 XT-23427 XT-24"
```

Comment: `/\bXT-\d+/g` to prevent things like `GXT-425345`.  `/\bXT-\d+\b/g` to prevent `XT-45GF53`. Only if desired.

Comment: I've added your recommendation @Karl-AndréGagnon. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    string = "efvss XT-123454 ghhsd efvss XT-6336 ghhsd efvss XT-554 ghhsd efvss XT-23427 ghhsd efvss XT-24";
    string = string.match(/(XT-)[0-9]{0,11}/g);
    document.write(string);
});
```

you can use the above code for your desired output
https://jsfiddle.net/ygpzq4hj/